# How can I obtain a list in which each item is a combination of another two lists items?

Tags: c#

The intention is to generate a list that contains for each value the combination of another two lists values separated by common separator. In psudocode;

```
my_list1= {a,b,c,d};
my_list2 = {e,f,g,h};
separator = " : ";
```

the expected output the given list should be;

```
my_output_list = my_list1 + " : " + mylist2;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what is expected output? is it `a,b,c,d : e,f,g,h`

Comment: By trying to do something maybe ? What did you try ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to get 16 results in your example?

If so, then you use can `SelectMany`.

```
var list1 = new [] { "a", "b" };
var list2 = new [] { "x", "y" };
var output = list1.SelectMany(x => list2.Select(y => string.Format("{0} : {1}", x, y)));
// output contains:
// [0] = "a : x"
// [1] = "a : y"
// [2] = "b : x"
// [3] = "b : y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var my_list1 = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var my_list2 = new [] { "e", "f", "g", "h" };
var separator = " : ";

IEnumerable<string> my_output_list =
    from item1 in my_list1
    from item2 in my_list2
    select $"{item1}{separator}{item2}";
```

I get:

```
a : e 
a : f 
a : g 
a : h 
b : e 
b : f 
b : g 
b : h 
c : e 
c : f 
c : g 
c : h 
d : e 
d : f 
d : g 
d : h
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one line Linq extensions:

```
var my_list1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var my_list2 = new List<string> { "e", "f", "g", "h" };

var my_output_list = my_list1.Select((item1, idx) => 
    string.Format("{0} : {1}", item1, my_list2[idx]));

foreach (var item in my_output_list) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Using a simple for loop

```
var my_output_list2 = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < my_list1.Count; i++) {
   my_output_list2.Add(string.Format("{0} : {1}", my_list1[i], my_list2[i]));
}
```